# s[i] in test counter of for loop in c

Tags: c

```
 main()
{
char s[ ]="man";
int i;
for(i=0;s[ i ];i++)
printf("\n%c%c%c%c",s[ i ],*(s+i),*(i+s),i[s]);
}
```

What is the meaning of s[i] in the for loop?

Answer (score 3):

once `i` is reaching 3 the `s[i]` will be `\0` thus ending the loop.

Remember, that `char s[]="man";` produces the following array:

```
char s[] = {'m', 'a', 'n', '\0'};
```

and that's why `s[3]` evaluates to a `'\0'` which causes the control statement to terminate the loop

Comment: There is no "conversion to boolean". Expressions controlling loops or if statements in C simply have their effect based on whether the value is nonzero.

Comment: You are correct, I was talking of logical "boolean". Poor choice of terminology on my side. I'll edit the answer to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

That's the predicate for the foor loop, and automatically gets converted to a boolean. It's like writing `s[i] != '\0'`. C strings are zero terminated.

Answer (score 0):

The loop continues as far as `s[i]` evaluates to a nonzero value. Since C strings are null (=zero) terminated, the `for` loop will increase `i` until all the string `s` has been examined.

Answer (score 0):

It's the condition of the for loop.

In C, any value different from NULL,'\0',0 is evaluated as true. So as long as s[i] doesn't take the '\0' it will be evaluated as true.

Answer (score 0):

Well in any for loop the middle statement is the condition for the loop, while that is true the loop will keep looping itself. The opposite of your statement (for example) would be `for(i=0;!s[ i ];i++)` meaning the loop would only repeat itself while `s[i]` is false.
Another example:

`for(i = 0; i <= 10; i++);` 
this loop will keep repeating itself as long as `i` is less than or equal to ten, thus making it simple way to count to 10 and perform an action every time i increments.